# Error with Dim, .Text = No error until startup, No text = Errors

Tags: vba

So I am trying to find out why my code for Visual Basic is not working, I am trying to make it so it has two text boxes in a way merge, cause I need them separate for the text next to them and I was going to use a variable to simplify this, but when I put in the code it didn't seem to work, it comes up with a BC30452 error when I take away the .Text from the 2nd one, and when I add the .text to both it gives me no errors until startup.

Code:

```
 Dim Night1 = N1Output And "-"  And N1

 Dim Night2 = N2Output And "-"  And N2

 Dim Night3 = N3Output And "-"  And N3

 Dim Night4 = N4Output And "-"  And N4

 Dim Night5 = N5Output And "-"  And N5

 Dim Night6 = N6Output And "-"  And N6

 Dim Night7 = N7Output And "-"  And N7

 Dim Night8 = N8Output And "-"  And N8

 Dim Night9 = N9Output And "-"  And N9

 Dim Night10 = N10Output And "-"  And N10

 Dim Night11 = N11Output And "-"  And N11

 Dim Night12 = N12Output And "-"  And N12

 Dim Night13 = N13Output And "-" And N13

 Dim Night14 = N14Output And "-" And N14

 Dim Night15 = N15Output And "-" And N15
```

I add .Text to the end of them and it'll have no initial errors, but upon start up it will not work if I use the button to open the form the code is located.
N1, N2, and the outputs are textboxes

Comment: `Dim Night1 as string:  Night1 = N1Output & "-"  &  N1`

Comment: What's N1, N2 etc., some variables or cells?

Comment: N1, N2 = Textboxes

Comment: @Backtalkers try the answer and code below

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of `Night`, and the just loop through all User_Form `Textboxes`, and for every pair populate the `Night(i)`.

Example, for the 3rd loop inside the `For i = 1 To 15`, it will take the values from the User_Form Control named "N3Output" add "-" and then also the value (text) from "N3" and put the in the array, inside `Night(3)` element.

Try the code below (should be inside your `User_Form` Module) :

```
Private Sub MergeTextBoxes()

Dim Night() As String
Dim i As Long

ReDim Night(1 To 15) '<-- redim Night array size to 15 (according to your example)

For i = 1 To 15
    Night(i) = Me.Controls("N" & i & "Output").Value & "-" & Me.Controls("N" & i).Value '<-- add values to all 15 array elements from User_From textboxes
Next i

End Sub
```